# Das Gegenteil von »archivieren«

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Gegenteil von *archivieren,* worunter ich verstehe, ein Objekt von einem Ort A oder B in ein Archiv zu bringen.
Das Gegenteil soll dementsprechend ausdrücken, dass ein Objekt aus dem Archiv wieder zurück an den Ort A oder B gebracht wird.

Am besten wäre ein einzelnes Wort oder Verb. Im Englischen könnte man bestimmt *unarchive* sagen; so etwas suche ich.

Comment: *Akten einsehen.*

Comment: Vielleicht _auslagern_?

Comment: Je nachdem, was du exakt suchst, könnte man eines der folgenden Wörter nehmen: "zurückholen", "abrufen", "entnehmen", "wieder erfassen", "zurückziehen". Jedes Wort passt aber in einen anderen Kontext. Und es ist tatsächlich nicht ganz klar, was du genau meinst.

Comment: "Wieder erfassen" trifft es schon ganz gut. Finde ich persönlich nur ein bisschen sperrig.

Comment: Kommt auf die Art des Archivs und des Nicht-Archivs an. _wiederveröffentlichen / republizieren_, _bergen_, _rauskramen_, ...

Comment: unarchive gibt's nicht - das heißt restore. Und restore heißt wiederherstellen.

Comment: Im IT-Bereich sagt man oft 'dearchivieren', wobei das kein "offizielles" deutsches Wort ist.

Comment: Im IT-Bereich heißt das Gegenteil von "archivieren" normalerweise "entpacken" :P. Aber das passt offensichtlich nicht auf reale Archive. Je nach Art des Archivs wäre unter Umständen "freigeben" eine Möglichkeit.

Comment: @Tim, "wieder erfassen" würde ich eher mit dem späteren erneuten Archivieren verbinden. Das Entnehmen aus dem Archiv passt m. M. n. nicht zu "erfassen"

Comment: Ja das kann sein. Ich habe mich auch für meinen Fall erst einmal für "wiederherstellen" entschieden. Auch wenn sich das mit dem gleichen "wiederherstellen", wenn etwas gelöscht war, doppelt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106282) is also asked in Stackexchange for the English language and the accepted answer for "What is the opposite of *to archive*?" is **to restore**.

Based on this answer, if this word is translated into German, the best-match translation may be:

> wiederherstellen

When I look at the example sentences on internet, they approve this translation as well;

> WhatsApp: So archiviert und stellt ihr Chats wiederher  - [source](https://www.netzwelt.de/tutorial/158206-whatsapp-so-archiviert-stellt-chats-wiederher.html)

oder

> Für die Archivierung und Wiederherstellung beliebiger Inhalte in einer
>   bestimmten Bibliothek - [source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_delete.htm&language=de&type=0)

Comment: The linked question is explicitely related to IT terms and processes. Only data is copied in or out of the archive. No physical objects are moved. As a native speaker I would never use "wiederherstellen" in the context of this question here because the object was not destroyed. It is just moved.

Comment: @Gerhardh: The data are, however, restored from the (scrambled) archived form into the original form, so I don't think "wiederherstellen" is wrong, and neither is "to restore". In other words: you *restore* the original (unpacked) state. "Man stellt den Originalzustand der Daten wieder her". Sounds fine to me.

Comment: You missed my point. This question here is not related to restoring data. It is about moving objects to and from an archive. Restoring is perfectly fine for data. The initial state was lost or destroyed and the data is restored. But if an object is moved to the archive, it is not destroyed and "wiederherstellen" does not make much sense.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Then you don't understand the meaning of "unarchive". The description in the question is a little confusing, but it is pretty clear (to me), that they mean unpacking files from an archive file. That is the meaning of "unarchive" in an IT context. See, for example, [here](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/u/unarchiv.htm): "**Unarchive** is a term used to describe the process of **restoring** files from an archive (compressed file) or backup to their original location, usually a hard drive."

Comment: @RudyVelthuis. Maybe you misinterpret the question. It is *not* related to files that are scrambled and restored to its location on a hard drive. It is not related to a zip file or similar. The question is clearly (for me) about physical objects (artwork, books, folders (paper, not electronic)) that are moved (not copied) out of an archive.

Comment: @Gerhardh: are you sure? The **accepted** answer mentions archiving chats, which is the compressing and archiving of files into a single archive file. Also, the word "unarchiving" has no other meaning than what I mentioned. To me, this means that is exactly what the question means.

Comment: RudyVelthuis, völig sicher bin ich mir nicht, gerade weil diese (m.M.n. falsche) Antwort akzeptiert wurde. Als Muttersprachler mit IT-Hintergrund fehlen mir in der Frage aber jegliche Hinweise darauf, dass es um eine Archivierung im IT-Kontext gehen könnte. In der IT werden keine "Objektve von Ort A nach Ort B gebracht". Vielleicht kann @Tim ja klarstellen, ob der IT-Kontext passt oder nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Der Sinn eines Archivs ist es, Dokumente unverändert aufzubewahren. Es wird nichts wieder entfernt (es sei denn, es gibt eine zeitliche Obergrenze, und der Inhalt wird regelmäßig teilweise gelöscht). Dass man ein Dokument wieder aus dem Archiv in das normale System zurücküberführt, kommt normalerweise nicht vor. Daher gibt es keine kurze Bezeichnung für diesen Vorgang.

Wenn ein Dokument gelesen werden soll, wird es wie bereits gesagt *eingesehen*.

Wenn ein Dokument irrtümlich archiviert wurde und wieder in den produktiven Gebrauch gebracht wird, muß man den Vorgang umschreiben, z.B. "die Archivierung rückgängig machen" o.ä.

Wenn Dokumente

Comment: Warst du noch nicht fertig, oder ist der letzte Abschnitt "Wenn Dokumente" aus Versehen stehen geblieben?